# Problem in javax.swing.SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have made a swings application but there is one problem in that which is as follow:

I have initiated a SwingWorker thread named "Thread-Main" from the Event Dispatch Thread and have passed a JLabel reference of the GUI to the "Thread-Main".

Now I have started 10 threads from the "Thread-Main".

Now I want that all the 10 threads should update the JLabel.

How can I do that?

Someone told me that I can do this by first making all the 10 threads subclasses of SwingWorker and then calling the publish("") method and passing the string in that "publish" method and then collecting all the published strings by the following method in "Thread-Main"

```
@Override
protected void process(List<String> labelStrings) {
    String count = labelStrings.get(labelStrings.size() - 1);
    label.setText(count); // label is a reference to a label in the GUI 
}
```

1. Is the above approach is correct to do that?
2. Should the 10 threads be subclasses of SwingWorker?
3. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **No** - This is the incorrect approach **if you want to control the number of threads** yourself.  Why?  Because if you look at the `SwingWorker` code you'll see that it uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` internally containing a maximum of 10 threads.  If you kick off a number of `SwingWorker`'s concurrently they will all run using this executor.  However, **you have no direct control over whether the background threads are executed in parallel**.
2. See point 1.
3. My recommended solution would be:

   - Create a single `SwingWorker`.
   - Within the `doInBackground()` method kick off 10 threads either directly or by using an `ExecutorService`.
   - Use a `CountDownLatch` or `CompletionService` to synchronize between your master thread (i.e. `SwingWorker` background thread) and worker threads.

**Example**

Define the number of worker threads to invoke and declare the JLabel to be updated.

```
final int nThreads = 10;
JLabel myLbl = new JLabel();
```

Define the unit of work we wish to execute as a `Callable<String>`.  The `String` result will be used to update the `JLabel`.

```
private static class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
  public String call() { ... }
}
```

Now kick off a `SwingWorker`, which will in turn kick off multiple parallel workers to do any processing.  The worker will not return a result via the call to `done()` (hence the `Void` type) but **will** marshall intermediate `String` results back onto the Swing thread by calling `process(String... chunks)`.

```
new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
  // See method definitions below.
}.execute();
```

Define `doInBackground()` to kick off the worker threads and block for each result using a `CompletionService`.

```
public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
  // Define executor service containing exactly nThreads threads.
  ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);


  // Define completion service that will contain the processing results.
  CompletionService compService = new ExecutorCompletionService(execService);    

  // Submit work to thread pool using the CompletionService.  Future<String>
  // instances will be added to the completion service's internal queue until complete.
  for (int i=0; i<nThreads; ++i) {
    compService.submit(new MyCallable());
  }

  // Take results from each worker as they appear and publish back to Swing thread.
  String result;
  while ((result = compService.take().get()) != null) {
    publish(result);
  }
}
```

Now we implement `process(String... chunks)` to simply update the `JLabel` when called.

```
public void process(String... chunks) {
  if (chunks.length > 0) {
    // Update label with last value in chunks in case multiple results arrive together.
    myLbl.setText(chunks[chunks.length - 1]);
  }
}
```

Finally we override `done()` to marshall any exceptions back onto the Swing thread.

```
public void done() {
  try {
    get(); // Will return null (as per Void type) but will also propagate exceptions.
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.show ... // Show error in dialog.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to use CountDownLatch. Which thread you means by master thread.

Comment: I have given a worked example above.  Rather that use CountDownLatch I've opted to use a CompletionService to capture the results.  The code is untested!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an easier approach is to wrap the code that updates the GUI in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) method.

Edit: In your individual threads whenever you want to update the label you do:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        label.setText(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes this is good approach if you don't need to do any synchronisation between your GUI and your worker threads other than update the JLabel (It's far simpler than my solution!).

Comment: If i follow this approach, then should the 10 threads started from the "Thread-Main" SwingWorker thread be subclasses of SwingWorker or Thread?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need 10 threads?  why won't one extra thread do?

the real question:  what is the problem you are trying to solve?

to answer your direct questions:

1) yes, that is the correct approach
2) yes, the threads should be SwingWorkers (if you are using netbeans, you can also use Tasks, which are subclasses of SwingWorker as well)

3) if you want to have a separate thread from the edt; then you need to use a swingworker; so that is the *way* to do it.

good luck!

Comment: I'm looking at NetBeans 6.9.1, and RequestProcessor.Task is not a subclass of SwingWorker.